# Running MySQL locally after MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4 Update

Tags: php, mysql, macos, macos-high-sierra

Having recently Updated my MacOS to the latest version 10.13.4, my Locally run version of MySQL (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for osx10.13 (x86_64)) would no longer start properly. I get the following error when I try to run it using mysql start: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2).
And When I try to run it using mysql.server start, sometimes it starts and works for a few seconds, before stopping again. 
Other times, I get the following error:
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/My-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).

When I navigate to this location /usr/local/var/mysql/My-MacBook-Pro.local.pid, I notice that the .pid file is missing, rather a .err file having the same name exists in it's stead. When I open this file I see that it contains nothing. And when I rename it have the .pid extension, mysql.server start works for a few seconds again, before I observe that the .pid file get changed to a .err file again (I observe this in realtime from a finder window).

Asides from Having to uninstall and reinstall mySQL again, I can't seem to find a practical solution. Last time I did this was around three days ago. And now it's stopped working again.

Could someone explain what seems to be going on?

Comment: Did you resolve this?